# Unable to load imageView from image array list

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-imagebutton

Herewith I need to load an Image Button dynamically with locally saved .png file. From internal storage of the device I collect the images found on particular folder. Its working fine.

```
List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures/Screenshots");
        if (!folder.exists()) folder.mkdir();
        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            String filename = file.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (filename.endsWith(".jpg") || filename.endsWith("jpeg") || filename.endsWith(".png")) {
                fileNames.add(filename);
            }
        }
```

log results as

> [123.png]

finally I need to set the background as 123.png image for the image button. To do that I have used inside the loop

```
String picName = fileNames.get(i);
            String picName1 = picName.replace(".png", "");
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(picName1,"drawable","com.test.ABC");
            imageView.setImageResource(resID);
```

At that moment I got this error

> 11-21 17:54:48.899 27250-27250/com.datamation.swdsfa W/ResourceType:
>   No package identifier when getting value for resource number
>   0x0000007b 11-21 17:54:48.904 27250-27250/com.datamation.swdsfa
>   W/ImageView: Unable to find resource: 123
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7b
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2350)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:433)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources.getDrawable(VectorEnabledTintResources.java:67)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:648)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:377)
>           at com.test.ABC.fragment.FragmentTools.ViewImageList(FragmentTools.java:342)
>           at com.test.ABC.fragment.FragmentTools.onClick(FragmentTools.java:287)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method which you are using `imageView.setImageResource(resID);` is for images present in `drawable` folders, but as you are saying `From internal storage of the device I collect the images found on particular folder.` seems like you are trying to use image stored in some directory in internal storage. So it won't work.

[Check this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))

You can try something like this,

```
File file = new File("some path");
if(file.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

To get path of default camera directory you can try like,

```
File picDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(picDir, "your image.png");
```

Comment: Thank bro. but Still not working for this path "DCIM/Camera/20181221_125634.jpg" without any errors

Comment: Got it. but if (file.exists()) inside not fired

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM

Comment: Thankx bro. Now I got an outofmemory error due to loop. But fired inside if condition. Now I'll fix it. Thankz again bro.... you saved my time

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply do this with Picasso or Glide

I'm giving the example to use Picasso.

```
File file = new File(filepath);
Picasso.with(activity).load(file).fit().centerCrop().into(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need change little bit code

```
List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures/Screenshots");
    if (!folder.exists()) folder.mkdir();
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        String filename = file.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith(".jpg") || filename.endsWith("jpeg") || filename.endsWith(".png")) {
            fileNames.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Pictures/Screenshots/"  +filename);
        }
    }
```

And you can use simply Picasso library to shoe the image into Image-Button

For Example

> Picasso.get().load(filename).into(yourImageButton);

for that you need to add library into gradle

> implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

For reference, you can use this link [Picasso](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library)